# How to use Not Exists in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza, correlated-subquery, not-exists, subquery

I have 3 tables in Netezza.

Table 1: STORES

```
CREATE TABLE STORES
(
    STORE_NAME CHARACTER VARYING(10),
    STORE_TYPE CHARACTER VARYING(10)
);
```

Table 2: CITIES

```
CREATE TABLE CITIES
(
    CITY CHARACTER VARYING(10)
);
```

Table 3: CITIES_STORES

```
CREATE TABLE CITIES_STORES
(
    STORE_TYPE CHARACTER VARYING(10),
    CITY CHARACTER VARYING(10)
);
```

I need to find the store_type which is present in all the cities. So I was trying to do this the following way. If for a particular,
`store_type` (present in `Stores` table) , I cannot find any state in which the `store_type` is not present, then that `store_type` is my answer.

I wrote the following query and run in Netezza:

```
select distinct
    store_type
from
    stores
where
    not exists (
                    select *
                    from
                        cities
                    where
                        not exists (
                                        select *
                                        from
                                            cities_stores
                                        where
                                            cities_stores.city = cities.city
                                            and cities_stores.store_type = stores.store_type
                                    )
               );
```

but it is giving an error as

> ERROR:  (2) This form of correlated query is not supported - consider
>   rewriting

Please tell me where I went wrong. Is this any problem with Netezza database?

Answer (score 0):

In general, correlated subqueries in Netezza are a bad idea. There are a lot of good resources that indicate this. In fact, Netezza attempts to determine the [equivalent join syntax for you](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.0.3/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/c_dbuser_correlated_subqueries_ntz_sql.html) instead of performing the statement as written. When it can't, you get that error.

To get around it, just write the equivalent join the first time.

```
select distinct
  store_type
from
  stores str
  left outer join cities_stores cts using (store_type)
  left outer join cities cit using (city)
where
  city is null
```

Note: you said that you wanted to find the `store_type` that is present in all the cities, but your statement returns `store_type`s that are *not* present in any of the cities. I rewrote your SQL, not what you indicated in the question.