# SQL: Understanding the NOT IN function

Tags: sql

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have the following table:

```
   student_id years
1         123  2010
2         123  2011
3         123  2012
4         124  2010
5         124  2011
6         124  2012
7         124  2013
8         125  2010
9         125  2011
10        125  2012
11        125  2013
12        125  2014
```

**My Question:** I only want to select students if they ONLY have years = (2010,2011,2012,2013). This means that in the above table, ONLY student_id = 124 will be selected.

Here is my query using the NOT IN function (first use NOT IN to choose students that do not meet the condition ... then use NOT IN to exclude students that do not meet the condition) :

```
SELECT student_id, years
FROM my_data
WHERE student_id NOT IN (
    SELECT student_id
    FROM my_data
    WHERE years NOT IN (2010, 2011, 2012, 2013)
)
```

However, this query is incorrectly  returning student 123 and student 124:

```
  student_id years
1        123  2010
2        123  2011
3        123  2012
4        124  2010
5        124  2011
6        124  2012
7        124  2013
```

**Can someone please show me how to fix this? The final answer should only return student 124.**

Thanks!

Comment: As happens so often, the problem lies in the description of the task. Your description is not precise, and you wrote a query matching that description. You say you want to select students that only have years 2010-2013, but you forgt to mention that there is another condition, namely that they must have all these four years. This condition is neither mentioned in your description nor implemented in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an aggregation approach here

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT student_id
    FROM my_data
    GROUP BY student_id
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN years NOT IN (2010, 2011, 2012, 2013)
                      THEN 1 END) = 0 AND
           COUNT(DISTINCT years) = 4
)

SELECT student_id, years
FROM my_data
WHERE student_id IN (SELECT student_id FROM cte);
```

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen : Thank you so much for your answer! I think the NOT EXIST function is not available in Netezza? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36580907/how-to-use-not-exists-in-netezza

Comment: @stats_noob `EXISTS` should be available, I think.  If not, then use the aggregation approach.

Comment: @ Tim: Thank you for your reply! I tried the second approach and it does not seem to be returning the desired result? https://imgur.com/a/WSnKOCw

Comment: You want students with all four years, is that right?  Check the update above.

Comment: thank you so much!  Btw I am still curious - why is my original code not working? I stated the logic for not selecting students that do not meet the condition ... thus, why is this not working?

Comment: Your subquery will return every student having even a single record which does not match 2010 to 2013.